# Python multithreading: threaded input() pauses other threads in one program, but not the other?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, sockets

I'm coding a small socket Chat Server for personal use, and have come across and issue.
My client is a simple program with two threads, one waiting on a user input, the other on the server; this code works perfectly:

```
import socket
import threading
from threading import Thread

username = input("Username? >")
host = input("host ip?")
port = 8000

Socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

Socket.connect((host,port))
Socket.send(username.encode())
print(Socket.recv(1024).decode())

def SendMessage():

    while True:

        Socket.send(input("").encode())

def RecvMessage():

    while True:

        print(Socket.recv(1024).decode())

msgthread = Thread(target = SendMessage, args = ())
recvthread = Thread(target = RecvMessage, args = ())

msgthread.start()
recvthread.start()
```

(Forgive the sloppy code, it was thrown together in ~20mins on a Monday evening)
As you can see, I am calling two threads, both of which have halting functions in them, and it works seamlessly.

The server, however, is where I am having problems:

```
import socket
import threading
from threading import Thread

connections = []
host = ""
port = 8000
threads = []

def ListenForCommands():

    while True:

        print(input())

def SearchForConnections():

    global connections, threads

    while True:

        conn, addr = Socket.accept()
        username = conn.recv(10).decode()

        conn.send(("You have successfully connected to the server!").encode()) 
        print(username + " (" + str(addr[0]) + ":" + str(addr[1]) + ") Joined")

        for i in range(len(connections)):
            if connections[i][0] != conn:
                connections[i][0].send((username + " Joined").encode())

        connections += [[conn,addr,username]]

        threads += [Thread(target = Listen, args = (conn, ))]
        threads[-1].start()

def Listen(conn):

    global connections, threads

    while True:

        for i in range(len(connections)):

                if connections[i][0] == conn:

                    username = connections[i][2]

        try:

            data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
            print(username + ": " + data)

            for i in range(len(connections)):

                if connections[i][0] != conn:

                    connections[i][0].send((username + ": " + data).encode())

        except:

            print(username + " Disconnected")

            for i in range(len(connections)):

                if connections[i][0] == conn:

                    connections.remove(connections[i])
                    break

            for i in range(len(connections)):

                connections[i][0].send((username + " Disconnected").encode())

            return;

Socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print("Server created")
Socket.bind((host,port))

Socket.listen(3)

ListenThread = Thread(target = ListenForCommands, args = ())
ListenThread.start()
SearchForConnections()
```

The source of the problem is in these functions:

```
def ListenForCommands():

    while True:

        print(input())

def SearchForConnections():

    global connections, threads

    while True:

        conn, addr = Socket.accept()
        username = conn.recv(10).decode()

        conn.send(("You have successfully connected to the server!").encode()) 
        print(username + " (" + str(addr[0]) + ":" + str(addr[1]) + ") Joined")

        for i in range(len(connections)):
            if connections[i][0] != conn:
                connections[i][0].send((username + " Joined").encode())

        connections += [[conn,addr,username]]

        threads += [Thread(target = Listen, args = (conn, ))]
        threads[-1].start()
```

The program seems to be halting when arriving at this line

```
print(username + " (" + str(addr[0]) + ":" + str(addr[1]) + ") Joined")
```

and works fine without it; however, on the Client Program, this does not seem to be the case.

the ListenForCommands function (as of now just printing out the user input) is being declared as a thread:

```
ListenThread = Thread(target = ListenForCommands, args = ())
ListenThread.start()
```

and the SearchForConnections function is being called normally. However, the entire program seems to be being halted until an input is taken from the user, unlike the client side which seems to be working perfectly.

I think I am missing something quite obvious, but have been at a loss for a few hours now, and would love it if someone could help me see the error in my ways!

Comment: Usually a good idea to sprinkle some more print statements in your program. "I'm about to do this", "Finished this, doing that", etc. That should tell you what is stalled / doesn't get to where you expect it.

Comment: You should check your indentation. Much of what you have doesn't look correctly indented and so (especially in python), it's difficult to see what your application logic is actually doing. The best way is to paste your entire code snippet in directly from your editor, then highlight the entire block of code and click the '{}' icon. Then your indentation will remain consistent.

Comment: Your code is broken with respect to handling disconnects. You will *not* get an exception on `recv` (normally) when a client goes away, you will instead get a null string returned from `recv`. You *will*, however, get an exception if you try to send to a client that has disconnected. So, with your current code, when you attempt to forward a string you received from client A to client B that has disconnected, your `except` clause is then going to close/remove client A, rather than the one that is the proximate cause of the exception, B.

Comment: Are you sure? The recv() function always creates an error for me when the client disconnects; that is, in fact, why I wrote that the way it is. The rest of the code is functioning properly, albeit haphazardly, but the threading is where I seem to be getting the problem.

Comment: Code has been reentered properly and spaced out for easier understanding.

Comment: You *may* get an exception from `recv` if you've *already* done something to cause the connection to be reset. For example, if you try to `send` to a client that has already disconnected, that will generate a TCP `RST` on the connection. The next time you call `recv` on that connection (after the `RST` has been received), you'll get an exception. So, in your design, you do need to trap `recv` exceptions. However, you should trap them separately from `send` exceptions so that you remove the correct connection.

Comment: ah, thank you, I understand now.